# Windows getting errors, that are not in Linux - Python

Tags: python, windows

I have the Problem, that my Python-script runs perfectly under Linux and Wine ... but not on my Windows-Machine.
This is my the part of my Pythoncode where i keep getting this error on Windows:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "test.py", line 191, in <module>
  main = test_class()
 File "test.py" line 72 in __init__
  for self.tag1 in root.findall(self.tag1):
AttributeError: test_class instance has no attribute 'tag1'
```

This is my Code at the given lines

```
files_xml = glob.glob("../data/*.xml")
for t in range(len(files_xml)):      
  tree = ET.parse(files_xml[t])
  root = tree.getroot()
  for child in root:
    self.tag1 = child.tag
  for self.tag1 in root.findall(self.tag1):
    self.keys7 = self.tag1.keys()
```

To answer the first comments - the .xml looks like this:
and all xml.files has the same look, but other names for the child.

```
<root>
    <recipe allow=" " application=" "/>
    <recipe allow=" " application=" "/>
</root>
```

Thanks to all commenters and all viewer, the problem were some .xml-files, which were practically empty. So i had to workaround them with:

```
files_xml = glob.glob("../data/*.xml")
for t in range(len(files_xml)):      
  tree = ET.parse(files_xml[t])
  root = tree.getroot()
  try:
    for child in root:
      self.tag1 = child.tag
        for self.tag1 in root.findall(self.tag1):
          self.keys7 = self.tag1.keys()
  except:
    pass
```

Comment: I would like to see what `tree.getroot()` does. By your indentation, if `root` is empty, the line `self.tag1 = child.tag` will not be executed, thus the next line `for self.tag1 in root.findall(self.tag1):` will raise an error. Are we talking about directories? Is the code OK with slashes and backslashes?

Comment: The indenting of the code in your question may be wrong -- shouldn't the second `for` loop be nested inside the first?

Comment: @Roberto: I posted one xml-file to my question. tree.getroot() returns me with root-tag and then self.tag1 will be recipe  And the code seems to be good with this, because the programms find the files normally under linux and windows. The problem is : why does it run perfectly fine under linux, but windows gave me the posted error

Comment: @Jenartor: With those lines of code I don't have an answer, but since `self.tag1` seems to be defined by the code `for child in root: self.tag1 = child.tag`, then if there is no `self.tag1`, it must logically be because `root` is empty.  Also, please consider @martineau 's advice, by your indentation `self.tag1` will be loaded with `child` values and only the last value will leave the loop - all the previous values are just cycled through, assigned and done with when `self.tag1` gets the next value.

Comment: Thanks for the advise for the second for-loop - i did'nt realize that. But the problem were some .xml which hasn't any childs ... only a <root></root> ... don't know why they are in this folder, when they practically empty ... but with a try: and except: i had a workaround for those empty files

Comment: @Jenartor: It's considered a bad programming practice to use a bare `except:` like you show because it catches _all_ exceptions, including `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` which shouldn't be ignored. Better to make it specific by listing only the exception(s) you want to catch.

Comment: @martineau: I think it is or isn't it? It's only for parsing the chosen .xml-files. So that the empty Files don't stop the program from running. And i think KeyboardInterrupt shouldn't come, because it have a gui for the windows-user